# How to install dependencies? Brackets.io

Tags: dependencies, libraries

I have installed Brackets.io and it opens and works fine.

Well, I say works fine - the program does but I guess it is missing some libraries as all of the menus appear as squares??

I have done ldd on the brackets application and it has returned a whole list of libraries it needs. However - how do I check what ones I have already? And if it is a case that I need all of them that have appeared following the ldd command - how do I install them all? Is it a case of painfully installing them one by one?

Regards

Comment: I don't see it in the app repo, did you compile it from source?

Comment: HellionWisp - Issue is now resolved. Initially I had simply installed from the Deb file I downloaded from the brackets website. However I then found a link to a solution where there is a repository that can be added and so I could simply Apt-Get brackets. It worked a treat and correctly installed all libraries. I will look for the link and post it in case anyone else has this issue.